# Php Configuration On Mac - Not rendering

Tags: apache, php

For some reason any php snippet does not render in my browser. I know it gets evaluated because it's not displayed as text either. I did the following:

1. In httpd.conf I found the load module line for the php5 lib and uncomented it
2. I renamed the php.ini.default to php.ini in the /etc dir
3. I restarted apache

That didn't work and there doesn't really seem much else that I can do. Any ideas what could be the problem?

I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8 (Leopard).

**Edit
Also my access_log and error_log for httpd look clean. No sign of errors. Also tried a different browser.

**Second Edit
If I have the file extension as php, the page gets rendered but any embedded php within html does not render.

Comment: http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html

Comment: Did you remember to put `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php`? And what do you see in your browser if you click View Source? It sounds like it isn't being interpreted at all, and browsers ignore `<?php` tags, so they wouldn't appear on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it could be a problem with mod_php. Basically, it sounds like Apache is running .php files using the PHP interpreter, but mod_php might not be configured correctly.

You might want to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: You're answer guided me towards what I was missing. I figured that because php files work then the interpreter was only set up to parse .php files and not html files at all. The following line with the addition of .html fixed it AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html